# How to install Django using source code in virtual environment?

Tags: python, django

My environment is in `/home/karan/envs/` and is called `env1`. My working directory is `/home/karan/` and django is on the desktop.

How can I install django in my environment using the local copy? Please tell me where I should `cd` so the installation is smooth.

Will `sudo python setup.py install` when the environment is activated work? Can that change my system files?

Comment: No need to use `sudo` in a virtualenv! Do you need your system files to be altered or do you want to avoid it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

- First Activate your virtual environment
- `cd` into the project folder
- then do `python setup.py install`

FYI you can use [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to install django.

```
pip install Django
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid pip for now, since I'm in India right now and Internet is terrible here. For `python setup.py install`, where do I place the django files?

Comment: Place any where but after activating the environment just `cd` into the folder where you have extracted django files. See my steps.

Comment: But if I cd to the django folder, won't it install it in my system? Or will the virtualenv prevent that?

Comment: It will go into the virtual environment. Later on test it simply by opening python shell and `import django    print django.__file__`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to start with a django project is keep all your requirements inside requirements.txt file. Then install it from **pip**.

For ex:- create a text file with the name as requirements.txt.

Inside that write all your requirements as below

```
Django==1.4
MySQL-python==1.2.3
ipython==0.13
```

Then save it.

Activate your env using this command: **source test_env/bin/activate**

Then use this command: **pip install -r requirements.txt**

It will install all your requirements inside the environment. Then you can run your project from env.

Hope this helps

Comment: Well I'm trying to avoid pip for now, since I'm in India right now and Internet is terrible here.